# VMFleet Diskspd script shows zeros in output.

Tags: stress-testing, iometer

Speaking shortly, I decided to stress-test my brand new 4-node S2D cluster.

I started with IOMeter and got the initial results (max IOPS/Throughput on different patterns). Then I thought it would be a good idea to find IOmeter configs that would simulate the real production workload. Sadly, I didn't find anything useful for IOmeter, but discovered the fancy Powershell script called **VMFleet** that uses MS Diskspd to stress the storage and simulates the "bootstorm".

I followed [this](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/deploy-vm-fleet-to-benchmark-your-storage-system) blog article during the configuration process to prepare and configure the lab.

**set-vmfleet.ps1** script showed me some errors so I replicated all the steps manually.

Next I ran **start-vmfleet.ps1** but it seems that output just shows zeros instead of actual results.

For how long should I run the **watch-cluster.ps1** to see the results? Have anyone used VMFleet before? This doesn't look like the expected behaviour.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The results should show-up immediately when you run "watch-cluster.ps1".

Did you ran "install-vmfleet.sp1" or just copied everything to the folder manually?

Comment: I see what you mean.. I have actually copied everything in the folder. Could it be causing the issue?

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the reason.